# Convenient and economic vector manipulation in NumPy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numerical-methods

Is there a means to manipulate matrices in NumPy without excessive use of `flatten()`, `ravel()`, creating tuples for creating every matrix, etc.?

I do understand it is not matlab but writing 40 chars instead of 4 doesn't seem very efficient.

For example:

```
A = ones(2,2) # doesn't work
A = ones((2,2)) # works with tuple
v = np.matlib.rand(2)
dot(v, A@v) # doesn't work: shapes are not aligned
vdot(v,A@v) # works
```

Now I want to update matrix column:

```
A[:,0]=A@v # nope! shapes are not aligned
# beautiful solution:
c = v.reshape(2,1)
c = A@c
c = c.flatten()
A[:,0]=c
```

Comment: Flattening and reshaping is not expensive.  Characters counts don't tell us much about computational speed.

Comment: Did either of the posted solutions work for you?

Comment: @Divakar Yours is the closest to the solution that, it seems, doesn't exist in NumPy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming the initialization of `A` is with `ones` from `numpy.ones`. We could have a one-liner, like so -

```
A[:,[0]] = A@v.T
```

**LHS :** `A[:,[0]]` keeps the number of dimensions intact as `2D`, as compared to `A[:,0]`, which would have a dimension reduced and thus allows us to assign `A@v.T`, which is also `2D`.

**RHS :** `A@v.T` takes care of the first two lines of codes :

```
c = v.reshape(2,1)
c = A@c
```

We don't need that third step of `c = c.flatten()`, because for `LHS`, we are using a `2D` view with `A[:,[0]]` as explained earlier.

Thus, we are left with a modified fourth step, which is the solution itself listed as the very first code in this post.

---

**Another way**

`A[:,0]` would be a `(2,)` array, whereas `A@v.T` would be a `(2,1)` array. So, `(A@v.T).T` would be a `(1,2)` array, which is *broadcastable* against `A[:,0]`. So, that gives us another way -

```
A[:,0] = (A@v.T).T
```

Comment: Thanks. Your answer has enlightened me that default NumPy vector is a row which is contradicting to the majority of math conventions I know.

Comment: @homocomputeris Yes, thinking in terms of MATLAB way, a 1D NumPy array could be best thought of as a row vector.

Comment: Concerning the 'Another way': I have `A@v.T array([ 2.,  4.,  2.])`, which is not (2,1), obviously. _Transposing a vector makes no sense since vectors are tensors of one dimension, that is, functions of one variable. NumPy will, however, comply and return exactly the same object._ (from _Scientific Computing with Python 3_)

Answer (score 1):

The argument signature for `ones` is:

```
ones(shape, dtype=None, order='C')
```

`shape` is one argument, not an open ended `*args`.

`ones(2,2)` passes `2` as `shape`, and `2 as`dtype`; so it does not work.

`ones((2,2))` passes the tuple `(2,2)` as `shape`.

Sometimes functions are written to accept either a tuple or an expanded tuple, e.g. `foo((1,2))`, `foo(*(1,2))`, `foo(1,2)`.  But that requires extra checking inside the function.  Try writing such a function to see for yourself.

Also `tuples` do not add computational costs.  Python creates and uses tuples all the time; Simply using a comma in an expression can create a tuple (if it isn't part of making a list).

Simply defining a function to take an open ended 'list' of arguments creates a tuple:

```
def foo(*args):
    print(type(args))
    return args
In [634]: foo(1)
<class 'tuple'>
Out[634]: (1,)
In [635]: foo(1,2)
<class 'tuple'>
Out[635]: (1, 2)
In [636]: foo((1,2))
<class 'tuple'>
Out[636]: ((1, 2),)
In [637]: foo(*(1,2))
<class 'tuple'>
Out[637]: (1, 2)
```

---

`v = np.matlib.rand(2)` doesn't work for me.  What is `v` (shape, dtype)?  `matlab` has a minimum 2d dimensionality; so I suspect `v` is 2d, maybe even a `np.matrix` class array.

`vdot` says it `flattens input arguments to 1-D vectors first`

---

Ok, with a special import I get `matlib` (an old compatibility package):

```
In [644]: from numpy import matlib
In [645]: matlib.rand(2)
Out[645]: matrix([[ 0.32975512,  0.3491822 ]])
In [646]: _.shape
Out[646]: (1, 2)
```

---

Let's try the double dot:

```
In [647]: v=matlib.rand(2)
In [648]: A=np.ones((2,2))
In [649]: A@v
...
ValueError: shapes (2,2) and (1,2) not aligned: 2 (dim 1) != 1 (dim 0)
```

Why does it work for you? For 2d arrays we can work directly with `dot`.  `@` sometimes works as an operator, but adds some of its own quirks.

(edit - later you use `A@c` where `c` is a reshaped `v`, the equivalent of `v.T` (transpose).)

```
In [650]: np.dot(A,v.T)     # (2,2) dot (2,1) => (2,1)
Out[650]: 
matrix([[ 0.63976046],
        [ 0.63976046]])
In [651]: np.dot(v,np.dot(A,v.T))    # (1,2) dot with (2,1) -> (1,1)
Out[651]: matrix([[ 0.40929344]])
```

Come to think of it, since `v` is np.matrix, this also works: `v * A * v.T`

---

We don't need to use `matlib` to make a 2d array of random floats:

```
In [662]: v1 = np.random.rand(1,2)
In [663]: v1.shape
Out[663]: (1, 2)
In [668]: np.dot(A,v1.T)
Out[668]: 
array([[ 1.63412808],
       [ 1.63412808]])
In [669]: np.dot(v1,np.dot(A,v1.T))
Out[669]: array([[ 2.67037459]])
```

Or if we skip the 2d, making `v1` 1d

```
In [670]: v1 = np.random.rand(2)
In [671]: np.dot(A,v1)
Out[671]: array([ 0.8922862,  0.8922862])
In [672]: np.dot(v1, np.dot(A,v1))
Out[672]: 0.79617465579446423
```

Notice in this last case, we get a scalar, not (1,1) array (or matrix).

`np.random.rand` is one those functions that accepts `*args`, the expanded 'tuple'.

---

In your last example you have to use `flat` because the `A[:,0]` slot is (2,) (if `A` were `np.matrix` it would still be (2,1)), while the @ produces a (2,1), which has to be flattened to fit in (2,)

```
In [675]: A@v.T
Out[675]: 
matrix([[ 0.63976046],
        [ 0.63976046]])
In [676]: A[:,0].shape
Out[676]: (2,)
```

With my 1d `v1`, `A[:,0] = np.dot(A,v1)` works without further reshaping.

In general, `matlib` and `np.matrix` functions add confusion.  There were created to make like easier for wayward MATLAB coders.

---

And the simplest way to calculate this:

```
In [681]: np.einsum('i,ij,j',v1,A,v1)
Out[681]: 0.77649708535481299
```

but with the (1,2) version we can do:

```
In [683]: v2 = v1[None,:]
In [684]: v2
Out[684]: array([[ 0.20473681,  0.68754938]])
In [685]: v2 @ A @ v2.T
Out[685]: array([[ 0.77649709]])
```

Comment: Thanks for the elaborated answer. The problem still the same, however. I do not care much about machine time but do care about mine. This is why I use `matlib`: it's the same submodule to access any matrix builder and I don't have to remember that `rand()` is in another one.

Comment: Sticking with the MATLAB conventions you could make A a np.matrix as well, and use `v*A*v.T`, and not need the flatten or reshape. Your complications result from mixing the two conventions. The is a `matlib.ones`.

Comment: Concerning my very first question, `np.matrix` and `*` will make me check every time that operations, say, `np.matrix(...) + np.array([[1,2],[3,4]]) # not from matlib` (or any other) haven't broadcast matrix to array and, thus, result in element-wise multiplication. So, more work for me and less for NumPy.